# How can I loop over all items in a dictionary which satisfy some condition? C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm currently working on a project where I have to loop over a dictionary. I only want to loop over the keys in this dictionary which contain a substring of a. So for a dictionary (key, value) I only want to loop through the pairs in this dictionary for which the key contains A.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

> How would I do this?

Dictionaries only offer O(1) (fast) access when checking for *equality*. There's not a way to "select" keys that *contain* a value without looping:

```
foreach(var entry in myDictionary)
{
    if(entry.Key.Contains("A"))
        // do something with entry.Value
}
```

You could use the `Where` method from Linq but it doesn't offer any performance improvement (it still loops internally):

```
foreach(var entry in myDictionary.Where(e => e.Key.Contains("A"))
{
    // do something with entry.Value
}
```

Comment: Compared to the `Where` alternative, this has the added adventage that it loops only once and filter and use in the same pass.

Comment: @Alejandro, `Where` return enumerable, I don't think it will loop more. .

Comment: @DragandDrop It loops twice, first inside the `Where` and then in the `foreach` loop. Not a concern most of the time, but certainly important on large dictionaries.

Comment: @Alejandro No it doesn't - `Where` just creates an enumerator that is not executed until the `foreach` (it used deferred-execution).

Comment: See [Reference Source for  WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,c7d6c8b578f62bef,references) it uses a while-loop in `MoveNext()` to skip non matching items; however, it does not have an additional `foreach` in `Where`, because it returns the iterator and not the items in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways. Here is one example (not tested).

```cs
var keys = dictionary.Keys.Where(k => k.Contains(a));
foreach (var matchingKey in keys)
{
    var value = dictionary[matchingKey];
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Compared to `dictionary.Where()` you must access the dictionary twice for each matching entry.